# SQLite 1.0.91.3 and EntityFramework 6.0.2 in VisualStudio 2013 project register sqlite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I create project with entityframework 5 and SQLite 1.0.91.3 and create entity data model. But after update entity to entityframework 6.0.2 I have error:

Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

How register System.Data.SQLite?

My config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestModel.csdl|res://*/TestModel.ssdl|res://*/TestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=D:\!Projects\ConsoleAppSQLiteEntity6\TestDatabase.db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.91.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.91.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.91.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.91.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Cant see your config file.

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: Hi. No I haven't a solution. I used SQL Server Compact database

Comment: Were you by any chance using Visual Studio Express?

Comment: Does your program have references to System.Data.SQLite* dlls, and do they have the "Copy local" setting to True ?